# Display DataTable with other data

Tags: datatable, laravel-7

I am going to display [DataTable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables). My controller code for DataTable is like below,

```
$data = Student::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                    $btn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>';
                    return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
```

But I have to show results of below data also in `View` file.

```
$product = Product::where('product_id',$id)->with('product_log')->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use get() as it will return collection, this will slowdown the loading speed of the table. Better if you pass query instead.
You might want to make another method for datatableble of product, and in blade call that method inside of datatable initialization for product table if you want to display it in datatable. Else you can pass the data in the method from where you are returning view.
Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks @Pragyan Shakya. Could you please help me with some sample code ?